# How to get the average of amounts for each row in DataGridView - C# .NET

Tags: c#

I have a `DataGridView` that displays grades for students in a gradbook program. I want to pragmatically find the average grade for each student in each row. Here is what the program looks like thus far.

[image]

This is what I have tried to do. However, it isn't working as intended.

```
foreach (DataGridViewRow row in sheet.Rows)
{
     <int> list = new List<int>();
     foreach (DataGridViewCell cell in row.Cells)        
          MessageBox.Show(cell.ToString());
}
```

What should I do? All help is appreciated.

Comment: Can you show the result you got from your code?

Answer (score 0):

If you're binding the Grid to a DataTable it would be best if you do the calculations in the DataTable - obviously you add up the score on each row and divide by the number of grades putting the result in the Average column.

An alternative to a DataTable is `List<Student>` where the `Student` is a class that contains fields including a calculated field for Average.

If you're using a Excel Spreadsheet you're can do the calculations in the loop, eg:

```
foreach (var row in sheet.Rows)
{
     int i = 0;
     float avg = 0;
     foreach (var cell in row.Cells)
     {
             i += 1;
             if (i > colAverage) {
             float grade = cell.value;
             avg += grade;
             }
     }
     row[colAverage] = avg / (row.Cells.Count - colAverage);
}
```